# Conditionally replace matching values from one data.frame to values in another data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a `df1` that looks like

**`df1`**:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  DE201 = c("A15", "A18"),
  DE207 = c("A903", "A906")
)
```

| DE201 | DE207 |
| --- | --- |
| A15 | A903 |
| A18 | A906 |

...
and another `df2` that has the dictionary values for those values, row wise

**`df2`**:

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  module = rep("Fall", 4),
  Data_Element_ID = c(rep("DE201", 2), rep("DE207", 2)),
  Data_Element_Name = c(rep("Injury result", 2), rep("Patient activity", 2)),
  Answer_Code = c("A15", "A18", "A903", "A906"),
  Answer_value = c("Yes", "No", "Ambulating with assistance", "Intracranial injury"),
  DE_original = c("DE201_A15", "DE201_A18", "DE207_A903", "DE207_A906")
)
```

| module | Data_Element_ID | Data_Element_Name | Answer_Code | Answer_Value | DE_original |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fall | DE201 | Injury result | A15 | Yes | DE201_A15 |
| Fall | DE201 | Injury result | A18 | No | DE201_A18 |
| Fall | DE207 | Patient activity | A903 | Ambulating with assistance | DE207_A903 |
| Fall | DE207 | Patient activity | A906 | Intracranial injury‬ | DE207_A906 |

...

I want to replace all the values in `df1`, including its column name, to be the matching values in `df2` (`df1` column names to be matched `df2`'s `Data_Element_Name`, and `df1` values to be matched `df2`'s `Answer_Value`)

for example, my desired output is something like

```
output <- data.frame(
  Injury_result = c("Yes", "No"),
  Patient_activity = c("Ambulating with assistance", "Intracranial injury")
)
```

| Injury result | Patient activity |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | Ambulating with assistance |
| No | Intracranial injury‬ |

...

I've tried below two methods but none of them worked, and merge/join are not really applicable here because they don't really have the same key/ID to join/merge by, since one is column wise elements , and one is row wise elements.
Tried `mutate()` with `if_else()` and `case_when()`:

```
mutate(
  DE201 = case_when(
    DE201 == df2$Answer_Code ~ df2$Answer_Value, 
    TRUE                     ~ DE201
  ),
  DE204 = if_else(
    DE204 %in% df2$Answer_Code,
    df2$Answer_Value, DE204
  )
)
```

Comment: Hello FloriaT, please do not provide images of your data and code. Use the output of `dput()` to share your data, and copy and paste your code directly into the question.

Comment: @Phil Edited, thanks

Comment: You created a table in the question instead of providing the output from the `dput()` function - this gives us extra work to convert into a usable format to help you. It would be far better to just paste in the output from that function. Also, please do not use the rstudio tag unless it is specifically about the IDE, which this question is not.

Comment: @Phil  my original df1 df2 from R is not representative to look at as you need to look through hundreds of rows to find what this question is trying to ask. The table is a simpler/dummy version of the df1 and df2. is there another way to simplify this?

Comment: A fairly intriguing challenge!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a more direct way of doing this, but it's not a straightforward task. In this case, I reshaped the data from `df1` to a long format using `pivot_longer()` in order to tie in the data from `df2` using `left_join()`. Then, it's a question of reshaping the data back to a wide format using `pivot_wider()` for those columns of data you wanted to keep.

Note that I'm adding a row id that I eventually discard because we need to keep track of what lines of data goes where when we are reshaping from wide to long back to wide.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 |>
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(-row_id, names_to = "Data_Element_ID", values_to = "Answer_Code") |>
  left_join(df2) |>
  select(row_id, Data_Element_Name, Answer_value) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Data_Element_Name, values_from = Answer_value) |>
  select(-row_id)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  `Injury result` `Patient activity`        
  <chr>           <chr>                     
1 Yes             Ambulating with assistance
2 No              Intracranial injury
```

Comment: thank u so much! I've tried this method on the whole dataset and it worked. Few questions, what does this "-" do in front of row_id in pivot_longer()? Does pivot_longer() actually works the same as gather() from `tidyr`? I just got suggestion to do mapvalues() from `plyr` as well and will try that to see if that works too. thank u!

Comment: @FloriaT The [`<tidy-select>`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tidyr_tidy_select.html) statement `-row_id` (or alternatively `!row_id`) selects every column *except* `row_id`.  In this example you give, those columns are {`DE201`, `DE207`}.  The `pivot_longer()` then "pivots" those columns, while keeping `row_id` as it is, to achieve a schema like this: `row_id | Data_Element_ID | Answer_Code`.  Since `row_id` keeps track of the original row in `df1`, then those rows can be "reassembled" into the final form; after the `*_join()` has been performed.

Comment: `pivot_longer()` is the new version of `gather()` yes (and `pivot_wider()` replaces `spread()`). Please select the checkmark to indicate that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table) 
dict <- rbindlist(list(df2[,c("Answer_Code", "Answer_Value")],
                       df2[,c("Data_Element_ID", "Data_Element_Name")]))
colnames(dict) <- c('key', 'val')

match_function <- function(column){
  dict[match(column, dict$key), 2, drop=F]
}

df3 <- as.data.frame(apply(df1, MARGIN = 2, match_function))
names(df3) <- dict[match(names(df1), dict$key), 2, drop=F][[1]]
```

Here is a step by step explanation of why it works. We create a dictionary using data.table and extract the key/val pairs. For example, the "Answer_Code" column is mapped to the "Answer_Value" column. Same for "Data_Element_ID" and "Data_Element_Name". I change the names to key and val for clarity.

```r
library(data.table) 
dict <- rbindlist(list(df2[,c("Answer_Code", "Answer_Value")],
                       df2[,c("Data_Element_ID", "Data_Element_Name")]))
colnames(dict) <- c('key', 'val')
```

The dictionary "dict" looks like this:

```
     key                        val
1:   A15                        Yes
2:   A18                         No
3:  A903 Ambulating with assistance
4:  A906        Intracranial injury
5: DE201              Injury result
6: DE201              Injury result
7: DE207           Patient activity
8: DE207           Patient activity
```

Now we can create a function which will take in a column, and replace the code/key with the name/val. We use apply with the margin of 2 (to iterate over columns) for this.

```r
match_function <- function(column){
  dict[match(column, dict$key), MARGIN = 2, drop=F]
}

df3 <- as.data.frame(apply(df1, 2, match_function))
```

df3 at this point looks like this:

```
  val                      val.1
1 Yes Ambulating with assistance
2  No        Intracranial injury
```

Now we just need to change the column names using the same dictionary process.

```
names(df3) <- dict[match(names(df1), dict$key), 2, drop=F][[1]]

df3
```

Our results match what you expected.

```
  Injury result           Patient activity
1           Yes Ambulating with assistance
2            No        Intracranial injury
```